# Parseval type lower bound on sum of squares of function projections

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

This is a followup to [this earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321597/averaged-parseval-relation-for-sampling-a-function-on-integers?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \{\pm 1\}.$ Assume that the support of $f$ is finite, say it is contained in $[1,N],$ it can even be taken to be $[1,N]$ if it helps. To avoid divisibility issues, assume that $N$ is is not divisible by any integer in $[1,m]$. One could, for example, take $N=m\#-1,$ where $m\#$ is  the $m^{th}$ primorial.

Define the fourier transform $\widehat{f}$ on $[0,1)$ by
$\widehat{f(t)}=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} f(n)~e^{-2i \pi n t}.$

Now let $v$ be a positive integer $\geq 2,$ and let
the "projected" function be
$$
f_v(n)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc} 
f(n), & \quad\mathrm{if}\quad & v|n,\\
 & & \\
0 & & \mathrm{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Of course $f_1$ is simply $f.$
Can one obtain a nontrivial bound of the form
$$
\sum_{v=1}^m \mid \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f_v(n) \mid^2 
{\geq} A(N,m) \int_0^1 \mid\widehat{f(t')} \mid^2 \,dt' 
$$
or similar, using some kind of uncertainty relation.

We can take $m\ll N,$ a fractional power of $N$ or even a power of $\log N.$

Comment: What prevents all sums on the left from being $0$? I mean, $N=m!$, $f(n)=e^{2\pi i n/N}$, say.

Comment: @fedja, please see edit.

Comment: The new condition is not scale-invariant and, thereby meaningless. Just perturb all values in my example by $c$ where $c$ is extremely small.

Comment: @fedja now I see. Thanks. I will update with a meaningful constraint, when I have time to think carefully.

Comment: @fedja please see new edit

Comment: @fedja gentle reminder